# Query archives by shortcode

Tags: php, wordpress, function

What's query for WordPress archives that I can put in functions and call by shortcode...

```
<?php do_shortcode('[archives]'); ?>
```

inside archive.php

Found get_queried_object();, I don't know is it right function.

Instead of

```
<?php while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
<h1 class="entry-title"><?php the_title(); ?></h1>
<div class="entry-content">
<?php the_content(); ?>
/* Custom Archives Functions Go Below this line */

/* Custom Archives Functions Go Above this line */
</div><!-- .entry-content -->
<?php endwhile; // end of the loop. ?>
```

I want to call it by

```
<?php do_shortcode('[archives]'); ?>
```

I want to make function, something like

```
function archives( $atts, $content = null ) {

if ( have_posts() ) : while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();

$return .= '<div class="archives_posts">';
$return .= '<div class="archives_posts_title">';
$return .= '<a href="'.get_permalink( $id ).'">'.get_the_title($ID).'</a>';
$return .= '</div>';
$return .= '</div>';
endwhile;
endif;
return $return;
}
add_shortcode( 'archives', 'archives' );
```

Answer (score 1):

Add following codes in functions.php of your theme.

```
function my_archives($params, $content = null) {

    extract(shortcode_atts(array(
        'type' => 'style1'
    ), $params));

    ob_start();
    ?>
   <div class="archives_posts">       
       <?php wp_get_archives( array( 'type' => 'monthly', 'limit' => 10 ) ); ?>     
   </div>

<?php return ob_get_clean();
}
add_shortcode('archives','my_archives');
```

You can change arguments to list archive posts as per your requirement.

Use following shortcode to get list of archive posts

1. Use `<?php echo do_shortcode('[archives]'); ?>` in template
2. Use `[archives]` in posts/pages

Comment: Manesh Timilsina, thanks for your answer. Is there way to make this function without arguments? Shortcode that works with any type of archive (monthly, category, author)? I just want to put default archive in shortcode. Reason is that I made Homepage works on shortcodes and I want to make archives work same way if possible.

Comment: I think it would be better to pass arguments from shortcode. For example:

'[archives type="monthly"]'

You can use argument passed from shortcode to meet your requirement.

Answer (score 0):

Add the following lines to your `/wp-content/themes/themeName/functions.php`:

```
function sc_archive(){  
    return wp_get_archives(); 
} 
add_shortcode('archives','sc_archive');
```

Then use it in your Page: `[archives]`.